# Have been gone for - acceptable?

Tags: meaning

> I have been gone to France for two months.
>
> Have you been gone to France lately?
>
> Is he here? No, he's been gone for 10 minutes.

I hear different opinions on the correctness of this structure.

Comment: What are those opinions?

Comment: The first example isn't remotely idiomatic to me. At first I thought this was something to do with *how long* something/someone has been gone, but I found [*The Roman Empire has been gone **for about 1,400 years***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+roman+empire+has+been+gone+for%22). Then I decided it's because OP's first example here is ***gone = away from here***, whereas mine is ***gone = no longer in existence***. But that's not the whole story, since I don't have a big problem with *John's been gone to lunch for about ten minutes* (it's a *bit* "awkward", though).

Comment: ...I did find [*I think he has been 'gone to lunch' for two years*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22i+think+he+has+been+gone+to+lunch+for%22), but as implied by both the semantics and the 'scare quotes', that's a deliberately peculiar construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Gone* can be both **static** (to be) and **dynamic** (to go). In your first two sentences, you are mixing the static form "*to be* gone" and the dynamic "*to* France". This is not allowed.

> I have been gone to France for two months.

This is incorrect.
"I have been gone" = "I am not here" / "I am away" / "I am not in the original place"

You could say:

- "I have been gone for two months. I am in France."
- "I have been away *in* France for two months so far."
- "I have been gone for two months." (I am still gone / I am still away)
- "I went to France for two months" (It is not clear if this was in the past, or if you are still in France)

> Have you been gone to France lately?

This is incorrect.

You could say:

- "Have you been to France lately?" (most common form)
- "Did you go to France lately?" ("*recently*" sounds better here)
- "Have you gone to France lately?" (less natural)

Both of the above sentences mean that you are no longer in France.

> Is he here? No, he's been gone for 10 minutes.

This is fine. It means that he *went* somewhere and *is* still gone/away.

If you want to ask someone if they have been *anywhere* recently, you could say:

- "Have been been away lately?"
- "Have you gone anywhere lately?"

Answer (score 5):

'The correctness of this structure' depends on the sense in which it is used.

*He's been gone for ten minutes* means 'he departed from here ten minutes ago'. That is perfectly idiomatic.

*To go to France* means to travel there; you don't need the verb *to be.*

> He has gone to France for two months.

(I changed the pronoun because if you were in France you would say *I have come to France*.)

> Have you been to France lately?

is more idiomatic than *have you gone to France?*